# Jenkins store unix password

Tags: unix, jenkins, pexpect

I have a design question. I am using jenkins to automate tasks. Let's say someone wants to perform taskA, he would run a pexpect file using jenkins and everything would be done automatically. Some of these tasks require to switch unix user and I was wondering if there is a more nice and secure way to get/set passwords for these users instead of just putting them in a property file. The solution I have right now is to ask the user to set the password in jenkins before running the task, and to put the passwords in a property file which will be used by the pexpect file. I know it's very bad to hardcode passwords but this is for internal tasks test only so if there is no other way to do it I'll probably go for that option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the solution was quite simple, I used 'Build with parameters' and passwords are sent to my server as password type parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You could use add Jenkins to the sudo list to allow the jenkins user to become anyone.